# My laptop restarts instead of waking up after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend, asus

My laptop is an ASUS GL552vw, running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

After suspending the system, when I open the lid to wake system up, it restarts the machine and I lose all my works.

This started happening after I ran `sudo apt upgrade`.
How can I fix it?

[Power Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G9l4.png),
[Additional Drivers Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4b7U.png)

Comment: No need (and no way) to "role it back". Updates are important. What you need to do is install the recommended Nvidia drivers. Open Additional Drivers and youĺl find it.

Comment: You need to review Power settings. As I know, suspended computers can be awaken by any other keys, but hibernated must be awaken by power button. Try to avoid using power button to awaken your laptop

Comment: @MichaelBay how can I downgrade my Nvidia drivers???
I just have one option Nvidia 375 in additional drivers :(

Comment: Why do you think you an older driver would be better? If you already installed drivers you should have mentioned that, along you the specific Nividia chipset (supposedly GTX960M) and how did you installed said drivers and what version. Also check power settings as commented before. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @MichaelBay every things in Power setting is OK! check it!
I don't know because i don't have any problem with version 352!